# C- Reading specific strings with quotes from a file

Tags: c, file

I am trying to read strings from a file. File contains below text:

```
<1a>This is line 1<1a>
<2f>This is line 2<2f>
<3c>This is line 3<3c>
```

In my program I get this value `1a` or `2f`. Based on this, I need to extract  that particular line like for `2f`, I only need to read `This is line 2` and save it in a buffer.

I have been able to read write using fopen fput but dont know how to read this.Can anyone please point me into some right direction which shows how to read this. Any demo code. Thanks.

Comment: You can use `fgets` to read lines from an open file

Comment: Show us what you have written so far and the corresponding output, it will be easily for us to help you. 
So if I understand well, you want to input in a function `1a` so that it returns the corresponding line between `<1a>`quotes ?

Comment: a) `fgets` then `sscanf` and check it by `strcmp`. b) `fgets` then extract by `memcpy` with `strstr`. .c)..

Comment: It is pretty much guaranteed that you'll have to read each line in turn from the beginning of the file until you come across the one you need.  You might then cache the location of the line in the file in case you need it again — but only if you're likely to need it again.  Unless you create an index (and the 'cache the location' is a variant of creating an index), you won't be able to find the right line in the file by many other mechanisms.  (You can memory map the whole file into memory and then search that way, if you like.)

Comment: Looks very similar to XML. If you changed (provided you can) the file format to really being XML, you could use one of the numerous xml libraries that are around...

Comment: @Badda Yes I need to read whats in between. And I am sorry I have not tried anything, I am still searching about this on google but havent found any good results.

Comment: @Aconcagua Did you mean ending with / like <1a>...</1a>. Yes this could be done. What are the libraries available.?

Comment: @Erica You would additionally have to add a root node around to get valid xml, though. Libraries for C are e. g. [libxml2](http://www.xmlsoft.org/) or [expat](http://www.jclark.com/xml/expat.html). For C++ (if you are willing to move to), there are even many more around (tinyXML, RapidXML, Xerces, ...).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int extract_line (char* line, char* buffer, char* ctag)
{
  char line_buffer[255] = {0};
  char* tagStart;
  char* tagEnd;

  if( strlen(line) < (sizeof(line_buffer)/sizeof(char)) )
  {
     strcpy(line_buffer,line);
  }
  else
  {
     printf("Line size is too big.\n");
     return 1;
  }

  tagStart = strstr(line_buffer,ctag);
  if(tagStart != NULL)
  {
    tagEnd = strstr(tagStart+1,ctag);
    if(tagEnd != NULL && (tagEnd > (tagStart + strlen(ctag))))
    {
        *(tagEnd) = '\0';
        strcpy(buffer, tagStart + strlen(ctag));
        printf("%s\n",buffer);
    }
    else
    {
      printf("Could not find closing tag.\n");
      return 1; 
    }
  }
  return 0;
}


int main ()
{
  char buffer[255] = {0};
  char line_buffer[255] = {0};
  char tag[] = "<2a>";

  char* cptr;
  FILE* data;
  data = fopen ("file.txt", "r");
  if (data == NULL)
  {
       printf("\n Failed to open file!");
  }
  else {
     while(( fgets( line_buffer, 255, data )) != NULL)
     {        
        cptr = strstr(line_buffer,tag);
        if(cptr == NULL)
        {
            continue;
        }
        if(!extract_line(line_buffer,buffer,tag))
        {
           //Do the rest of processing
           puts(buffer);
           strcpy(buffer,"");
        }
     }
     fclose (data);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

<strike>Basicly, what you need to do is get the tag field and use it as a delimeter to exctract the token.</strike> Just get the line tag and then use it to exctract the data.

Comment: Thank you for the remarks, @BLUEPIXY. I was fixing the code in chunks and testing in cpp.sh isn't the most convenient.

Comment: Modified the solution again to address the newly highlighted issues. Thanks again for the reviews @BLUEPIXY!

Comment: Is it OP's desired behavior?

Comment: ... Silly me, didn't see that at all.

Comment: 1) `cptr = (line_buffer,tag);
        if(cptr == NULL)` This has no meaning. 2) It is necessary for the caller to clear `buffer` beforehand and it is necessary to check whether the post execution value has been set.

Comment: Also, in this approach it may be a problem if there are multiple extraction points per line. However, it does not mention OP. So its necessity is unknown.

Comment: cptr = (line_buffer,tag); if(cptr == NULL) >>>> cptr = strstr(line_buffer,tag); if(cptr == NULL). The point was to skip the line if the tags we look for aren't present (and obviously I've missed to write it when editing the answer)

Answer (score 0):

```
char* returnSpecificString(char* valueBetweenQuotes)
{
  FILE* file= fopen("test.txt", "r"); // Open in reading only mode
  char *line= malloc(sizeof(char[150]));
  if (NULL == line) // Checks if enough memory
    fprintf(stderr, "Not enough memory. \n");
  else
  {
    while(fgets(line, sizeof(line), file)) //Iterate until end of file
    {
       if (strstr(line, valueBetweenQuotes) != NULL) // Meaning it's the line we want
       return functionToExtractTextBetweenQuote();
    }
  }
  return line;
}
```

As for the `functionToExtractTextBetweenQuote()` I advise you look functions like `strtok()` `strchr()`or `sprintf()` which will help you extract what you want from a string. I know this is unsufficiant but I ain't got the time to finish it now so I hope it will help you.

Comment: `strchr` --> `strstr` ? and This code is also insufficient as a pseudocode.

Comment: Both could be useful, depending on how she does it. I think strstr() is useful when you know what string you are looking for, which might not be the case here

Comment: First of all note that the type of argument is different.